# Scala: equivalent of collect + partial function for mutable data?

Tags: scala

(edited with shorter version of the question)

I want to mutate some objects in my collection with a partial function. Foreach doesn't allow for that. I can do it with collect, but there's a side effect on creating new collection, which I'd prefer to avoid.

Comment: Which mutable collection are you using?

Comment: You can't actually `filter` mutable collection (since `remove` on such collection can take more time than creation of new one). You could use `transform` method as equivalent of `map` method, for mutating an original collection.

Comment: I am actually using a collection of mutable objects (whether the collection itself is mutable or not is not important for my problem), and my intention is to mutate some of the objects in the collection with a partial function. Sorry if that wasn't clear in the original post.

Comment: @user2052791 Yep, your comment helped a lot in understanding your problem. Maybe you could edit your question with a clearer one, so future readers can understand it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so we're mutating data in any type of collection. I typed together this example data structure:

```
case class StringData(var value: String)
case class IntData(var value: Int)

val list = Seq(StringData("something"), IntData(1), IntData(2), IntData(3))
```

So the built in way of doing this is using `foreach` and two cases:

```
list.foreach {
  case i: IntData => i.value = i.value + 1
  case _ => Unit
}

list.foreach(println)

// StringData(something)
// IntData(2)
// IntData(3)
// IntData(4)
```

If we really want to omit the `case _ => Unit`, then we can do a little Traversable [Pimp](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766):

```
implicit class TraversableExtension[T](collection: Traversable[T]) {
  def foreachPf(pf: PartialFunction[T, Unit]) = collection.foreach(pf.lift)
}

list.foreachPf { case i: IntData => i.value = i.value + 1 }

list.foreach(println)

// StringData(something)
// IntData(2)
// IntData(3)
// IntData(4)
```

So what makes this work? The `lift` function takes the PartialFunction and applies it if it can and returns with the result in a `Some`. If it can't then it just becomes `None`, instead of a `MatchError` that happens when you don't have a `case _ => ...`.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that, if there's no way to do it just with existing classes, that doing a little pimping would be the way. Thanks for laying out the code.